# UWP remove focus border in a Gridview

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am pretty new to Universal Windows Platform (UWP) and XAML.

I have a GridView that shows data stacked vertically. That works fine but when I press and hold on one of the GridView.ItemTemplate/DataTemplate I get a gray border:

[image: Pressing and holding a DataTemplate]

I have tried to put these properties on various items but without success:

```
FocusVisualPrimaryThickness="0" 
FocusVisualSecondaryThickness="0" 
FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="Black" 
FocusVisualSecondaryBrush="Black" 
FocusVisualMargin="0"
```

I have also notices this on those properties. Does this mean it is not yet implemented?:

[image: TBD]

Here is my code:

```
<GridView x:Name="IconGridView"
                  Canvas.ZIndex="2"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  Margin="398,728,402,107"
                  ItemClick="Clicked_On_Video_Preview_Image"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  IsSwipeEnabled="True"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind _videoItems}"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                  BorderThickness="0"  
                  SelectionMode="None"
                  BorderBrush="Black"
                  Background="Black" IsHoldingEnabled="False">

            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Background="Black" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>

            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:VideoItem">
                    <StackPanel Margin="30,0,30,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Black" Height="245">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border Name="PreviewBorder" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#000000" Margin="0,55,0,55">
                                <Image Height="135" Width="240" Source="{x:Bind ThumbnailFilename}" Loaded="Video_Preview_Loaded" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                            </Border>
                            <Image Margin="0,55,0,55" Height="29" Width="29" Source="Assets/play_vit.png" />
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,185,0,0" Text="{x:Bind Title}" CharacterSpacing="200" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Foreground="white" Width="240" Height="45"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

Comment: I believe this is the result of the default style for the GridView. The solution would be to create a custom style based on the original, modify the part of the gray border and use it in your desired GrdiView.

Answer (score 3):

The gray border is part of the `GridViewItem` template. If you want to modify it, you'll need to create your own template.

You can easily do that by right-clicking the control in the designer, clicking on *Edit Style*, then *Edit a Copy*, this will give you the default Style and Template to modify for your own needs.

In my case, I didn't want to modify the template at all, just wanted to get rid of it, so I simply replaced the template with a `ContentPresenter` to show my own content only, like so:

```
<Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <ContentPresenter ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you're wondering where the all those `TemplateBinding` bindings came from, I simply copied them from the default style. I could have just written `<ContentPresenter />` but I prefer to do it this way.

Hope this answered your question!

Comment: thanks. this removes the focus borders. however there are 2 issues (1) regular item borders are also removed (2) user needs to select/click on the item text itself to select it (doesnt work when user selects/clicks near or around the item as usual)

Comment: The code example I gave removes everything except the content I set, which was what I personally wanted to do. Follow the instructions in the second paragraph to get the default template, then modify it as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

This is the focus visual that is displayed for each GridViewItem when the user uses the TAB key to change the focused element. You can remove the focus visual, but it makes your app less accessible now because people won't be able to use the keyboard to navigate your UI (and narrator won't be able to read out the focused item).

```
<GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    </Style>
</GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Instead, if you want to change the appearance of the focus visual, you need to set the `Focus*` properties on each GridViewItem:

```
<GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryBrush" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryBrush" Value="Blue" />
        <!-- etc -->
    </Style>
</GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Hi Decade Moon. Thank you for your answer but I still got the problem. I should have maybe been more clear. I am devoloping a touch application. So a keyboard will not be used. If I implement your suggested anwer I still get the same result. Although when I connect a kayboard and start useing tab, then the Focus* properties comes in play. Then I see a red and blue border. I am trying to disable the focus border when I *Touch and hold" an item.

Comment: Can you confirm for me that if you apply the above style you get a gray border when you touch and hold and a red/blue border when you use TAB key? Or do you get a red border when you touch and hold? If it's the latter, then it is still the focus visual we're dealing with, otherwise it could be something else. I don't have a touch device so I can't reproduce it exactly as you did, but I did run it in the simulator (which does simulate touch) and setting IsTabStop to false worked for me. You've set SelectionMode to None, so I don't know what else could be causing the border.

Comment: Correct. I get gray border when I 'touch and hold. I get a red/blue border when i connect a keyboard and tab to that item. If I have "IsTabStop" on true then I can not tab to that item but I still got gray border when I "touch and hold".

Comment: do you have solution for this? How can I set the ForcusVisualMargin? I want to remove the focus margin